# Does "created" "sponsorship" github webhook event only fires once for recurring sponsorship?

Tags: github, webhooks

I am listening for "sponsorship" "created" github webhook event (https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads?actionType=created#sponsorship). It is firing every time for one-time sponsorships, which is ok. My question is regarding recurring (monthly) sponsorship. Will the "created" event be fired on every payment of a single recurring sponsorship (every month)? Or only on the creation of the recurring sponsorship?

The only way to check seems to be subscribing to the event and wait for 1 month. Which is not perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub support provided the answer:

> Hi there Alex,
>
> Thanks for getting in touch.
>
> I checked with our engineering team, and recurring sponsorships should
> only fire a webhook as they are created (not each month).
>
> I hope that helps to clarify, but please let me know if you have any
> further questions. ﻿ Thanks